# How to unit test custom Application class?

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, mockito, android-testing

I would like to write some unit tests for my custom `Application` class but my tests fail immediately after I try to create `Application` object with this error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Stub!
    at android.content.Context.<init>(Context.java:20)
    at android.content.ContextWrapper.<init>(ContextWrapper.java:21)
    at android.app.Application.<init>(Application.java:36)
    ...
```

This is my `Application` class:

```
class MainApplication : Application() {

  @Inject lateinit var statLogger: StatLogger

  override fun onCreate() {
    super.onCreate()
    inject()
    setupStatLogger()
  }

  private fun inject() {
    ...
  }

  private fun configStatLogger() {
    statLogger.config()
  }
}
```

And this is my test:

```
class MainApplicationTest {

    val app = MainApplication().apply {
        statLogger = mock()
    }

    @Test
    fun `logger is configured`() {
        app.onCreate()    
        verify(app.statLogger).config()
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can modify your application class to something similar to MVP and/or test the testable components of your Application class in isolation.

You are injecting your StatLogger and the checking the config on it. You can get a copy of your StatLogger under test and then check the config outside of the Application class too.